# Understand series in collection during iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say we have the following array:

```
%w(apple apple apple banan orange orange tomato orange apple apple)
```

Could I output, while iterating over the collection, "here comes 2 oranges" or "these were 2 oranges"?

**Update**
There could be more occurances of the same item in the collection, but what I'm concerned about is the series - how many there are one after another when they are of the same kind.

Comment: `puts "here comes #{array.count('orange')} oranges"` will work ? If not.. You should ask more clearly.

Comment: Well.. Look this - http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/slice_before

Comment: Wow thanks. If you got the time, could you please provide an example of an implementation?

Comment: You asked this question about a week ago, but have not selected an answer.  That may have been your intent, but if you found @Stefan's answer helpful, you should select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
arr = %w(apple apple apple banan orange orange tomato orange apple apple)
arr.chunk { |e| e }.to_a
# => [["apple", ["apple", "apple", "apple"]],
#     ["banan", ["banan"]],
#     ["orange", ["orange", "orange"]],
#     ["tomato", ["tomato"]],
#     ["orange", ["orange"]],
#     ["apple", ["apple", "apple"]]]
```

With an `each` loop:

```
arr.chunk { |e| e }.each { |e, a| puts "#{a.size} #{e}" }
```

Output:

```
3 apple
1 banan
2 orange
1 tomato
1 orange
2 apple
```